# how can resolve this error ( No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!) in angular test about firestore?

Tags: typescript, testing, google-cloud-firestore

in my angular test i have this problem in some componente and in the service where i use firestore.
for example this is a error in my itemservice:
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ItemService -> AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Item } from '../../environments/item';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ItemService {
  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item> | undefined;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  idField: any;
  itemDoc: any;
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = this.afs
      .collection<Item>('items')
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('items');
  }
}
```

and here is my app-module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreModule,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ItemsComponent } from './components/items/items.component';
import { ItemService } from './services/item.service';
import { ItemComponent } from './components/item/item.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
import { CartComponent } from './components/cart/cart.component';
import { CartService } from './services/cart.service';

import { AddItemComponent } from './components/add-item/add-item.component';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ItemsComponent,
    ItemComponent,
    NavComponent,
    CartComponent,
    AddItemComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'project2'),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ItemsComponent },
      { path: 'details/:id', component: ItemComponent },
      { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
      { path: 'newitem', component: AddItemComponent },
    ]),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [CartService, ItemService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431785/angular-fire-no-provider-for-injectiontoken-angularfire2-app-options

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message error, and this work for me:

import (in all test carpets that have use firebase):

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

and:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule
      ],
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```

That, works for me

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try by replacing:

`AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'project2'),` with
`AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),`

The method `initializeApp()` recieves only the firebase config since the change from `angularfire2` to `angularFire`

As it is mentioned in the [AngularFire Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)  it is only passed the firebase configuration as it contains the app name.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but nothing changes when i do the test.

Comment: Thanks I was having the same issue and this solved my issue