# Angular Fire - No Provider for InjectionToken (angularfire2.app.options)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

### Context

I am working with **Ionic & Angular & Angular Fire & Firebase**. I already made a **successfull connection** to the **Firestore Database** and I am able to manipulate the data.

### Specifications

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.11
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.2.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 13.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
   @angular/angularfire          : 7.2.1
```

### Implementations

**App.module.ts**

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      ...
      provideFirebaseApp(
          () => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)), 
          provideAuth(() => getAuth()), 
          provideFirestore(() => getFirestore(),
      ),
    ],
    ...
})
```

Now I am working on the integrattion of **Google Authentication**. For that I have been following the [Angular Fire Repository](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) and of course the [Angular Fire - Authentication Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md). Where's an abbreviated look of what's implemented (just like the docs):

**Login.page.ts**

```
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';

export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(private authenticationSvc: AuthenticationService) { }

    login() { this.authenticationSvc.login(); }
}
```

**Authentication.service.ts**

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }

    login() { this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()); }
}
```

### Problem

Simply put if I use the **Authentication.service.ts** on the **Login.page.ts** the application doesn't work anymore. The browser console outputs the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(LoginPageModule)[AuthenticationService -> AuthenticationService -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(LoginPageModule)[AuthenticationService -> AuthenticationService -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11120:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11287:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:4765:1)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:4769:1)
    at Object.AngularFireAuth_Factory [as factory] (angular-fire-compat-auth.js:126:1)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:11457:1)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11276:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:4765:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1216:1)
    at zone.js:1329:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.push.6084._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25535:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.push.6084._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:1)
    at Zone.push.6084.Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:632:1)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Solution

On the file **app.module.ts** add the following provider object:

```
import { FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from '@angular/fire/compat';

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebaseConfig }
    ],
})
```

All props go to @Saumya answer on this [question](https://software-testing.com/topic/366351/no-provider-for-injectiontoken-angularfire2-app-options-ionic6/2#1).

Comment: ionic 6 onwards there is no more app.modules.ts

Answer (score 2):

for later versions use or atleast doublecheck the correct object name i.e environment.firebase

```
import { FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from '@angular/fire/compat';


@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase}
    ],
})
```